# Initializing subclass object in class - StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, object, initialization, stack-overflow

I stripped my code to the parts that cause the problem. The code jumps back and forth lines 5 and 9 here, causing stackoverflowexception.

How could I do this differently? I need the Platform instance inside Game class to use in functions.

```
namespace Games
{
    public class Game
    {
        private Platform platform = new Platform();
    }
    class Platform : Game
    {
        private bool[] squares = new bool[9];
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't make `Platform` a sub-class of `Game`.

Comment: Finally. That fixed the issue, thank you so much! This is for a school assignment and I think I read the class diagram wrong.

Comment: +n; in my opinion, this is the perfect question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

When a `Game` instance is created it creates an instance of `Platform` which will invoke the base class constructor which creates an instance of `Platform` which will invoke the base class constructor which will...

See where this is leading?

You should use `Platform` where you are trying to use `Game`. Many would argue not to use inheritence at all. Consider composition which in your case might mean `Game` has a property of type `Platform` but `Platform` does not inherit from `Game`.

Comment: That makes sense now. I tried to solve this badly and figured something like this was happening, but that's so nicely explained. Thank you sir.